# Multiplication a number nth times

Tags: r, multiplication

New to R.

I have 2 columns 'X' and Y  (x*0.78) repeated Y times as shown below

[image: table of values]

I am trying to multiply 'X' by 0.78 Y (nth)times e.g. x*0.78=ans*0.78=ans*0.78=ans*0.78.... however many times specified in row Y

So far have tried through writing own function but failed

Comment: Could you show the function you have tried writing?

Comment: HI josh. I couldn't find it in my code. However,  I just got error every time with it the closed I have got thus far is >rep.int(x*0.78,y)
   [1]  3.8844000  3.8844000  3.8844000  3.8844000
                                                                                                       This just repeats the first multiplication nth times and does not do the successive multiplication I require.

Comment: my_data <- data.frame(x = c(4.98, 6.64, 1.66, 0, 3.32), y = c(18,5,8,10,8) )
my_data$ans = my_data$x*0.78^my_data$y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
# sample data
my_data <- data.frame(x = c(4.98, 6.64, 1.66, 0, 3.32), y = c(18,5,8,10,8) )

my_data$ans = my_data$x*0.78^my_data$y
my_data$ans

#[1] 0.05687641 1.91708378 0.22743899 0.00000000 0.45487797
```

Or

```
library(tidyverse)
my_data <- tibble(x = c(4.98, 6.64, 1.66, 0, 3.32), y = c(18,5,8,10,8) )

my_data %>% 
  mutate(ans = x * 0.78^y)
```

Comment: Second one is perfect. Thank you so much!